# Can I re-download pre-loaded games that came with my 2DS if I accidentally removed them?

Tags: nintendo-3ds-3dsxl-2ds

While minding my own business, I accidentally completely formatted the SD card in my 2DS. I had Mario Kart 7, Zelda OOT, and Pokemon Alpha Sapphire pre-loaded on there.

Can I somehow re-download or recover those pre-loaded games?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, after reformatting the SD card, you should be able to redownload them at the eShop. If that doesn't work, then i'm afraid you're out of luck.

Comment: Seems like you can : 'If you choose to delete the content off the SDHC Card or microSDHC card, such as during a system transfer, the pre-installed game will be available for redownload from the target system's Nintendo eShop after the transfer has been completed.' but I wonder for people who haven't used the eShop at all so don't have any data synchronized telling that they owned the game ... (http://en-americas-support.nintendo.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/14143/~/information-about-pre-installed-games-on-nintendo-3ds-family-systems)

Comment: Even then, you'll still be able to redownload it.  The data for telling whether or not you own the game stays on the SD card after deleting it. Even if you never touched the eshop, The option to redownload will still be up!

Comment: @Thepicausno  Unfortunately, the asker “completely formatted the SD card”.  What you said is Something Good To Know, but unhelpful in their situation. :-(

Comment: If you reformat your SD card to the point where you would lose your data, I'm not sure it would even be compatible with the system.